# Xcode C++ omp.h file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4, openmp

I’m trying to include openmp to my Xcode C++ project. I have changed my compiler in Xcode to LLVM GCC 4.2, added ”-fopenmp” as a CFlag and enabled OpenMP support in xcode as well. But it still says ”‘omp.h’ file not found” and i am unable to build the project. Does anyone know what could be wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add "OpenMP" as a sub-project within your own project? You should edit this question to show what your list of files looks like... it may just be that you need to specify a more precise path to the file, e.g. " `#include "openmp/omp.h" `".

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Try going to the project navigator using the panel at the left side. Select your project (the one with the blue icon), and a different main window appears. Here, click the relevant file under "Targets" and choose the "Build settings" and "All". Here, search for OpenMP. In my system, it shows up under "LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language". Set "Enable OpenMP Support" to Yes. This should make it work. Make sure to not manually #include "omp.h".

The weird thing is that I don't know how to do this "manually" (i.e. circumventing the built-in Xcode I approach described above).