# Xcode 11 MATLAB generated code : 'omp.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, matlab

I have written a MATLAB 2019a function that I want to export via codegen. I want to run this C function on my iPhone. Here is how I am exporting the function via codegen:

[image]

When I export it, a very large portion of my .h files have this include header:

```
#include "omp.h"
```

XCode states that 'omp.h' file not found.

This is odd to me, as when I've exported on older Matlab versions never was omp.h file included. Looking around the net, there are several questions that talk about this missing file, such as :

[Xcode C++ omp.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999255/xcode-c-omp-h-file-not-found)

[How to include omp.h in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990296/how-to-include-omp-h-in-os-x)

However, the authors of this question seem to advertently want it. I suspect that I am just running the MATLAB codegen incorrectly, thus requiring it's use.

**Questions**:

Should I export differently via codegen to allow my code to work on an iPhone?

If I exported correctly, where would I want to fetch the omp.h file from in order to run the exported code on an iPhone?

Comment: XCode does not support OpenMP. Your solution to disable it is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding an option to disable it, by selecting no in the image below, and it removed the code from having omp.h

[image]